# Application cannot be run in win32 mode in windows 2003

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I have encountered a problem while trying creating a windows CE application by VS 2008.

My OS is: windows 2003 server - 32 bits.

I opened the VS 2008, and choose: tool + connect to device + windows CE device:

Connection failed. ActiveSync is not installed.

So, I did as suggested on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708(v=vs.90).aspx, copied from (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\CoreCon\1.0\Target\wce400\x86) to c:\windows

When running conmanclient2.exe as suggested I got an exception:

The C:\WINDOWS\system32\ConmanClient2.exe application cannot be run in Win32 mode.

1. Why is the problem?
2. I need to run Windows CE 6.0 (not mobile), and I think that the above version is CE 4.00.
   Where can I find Windows CE 6.0 for VS 2008 (not R2, just Windows CE 6.0)?
3. What is ActiveSync for?
4. Is VS 2008 best version for Windows CE 6.0, or shall I use other VS version?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ConmanClient2.exe` is a Windows CE application.  You run it on the target device, not your PC.
2. You don't need "Windows CE" for your PC (there isn't such a thing anyway).  A Windows CE OS is already on your target device.  You only need an SDK and Visual Studio 2008 Pro.
3. You don't need ActiveSync.  Just use the instructions for using corecon (configure Studio, run conmanclient and cmaccept on the target device)
4. Yes, that is the version you need to be using.

Comment: For 2 - What SDK? Is there any Microsoft SDK? For Windows CE Emulator (tool + connect to device is the emulator?) Where is emulator for Windows CE 6.0? Also, how on what shall I develop (Windows Application is fine?) Need some tutorial for that, please.
Thanks :)

Comment: There are no emulators.  If there were I wouldn't recommend them anyway.  Use real hardware.  Always.  You must use a "Smart Devcie Application" in Studio.  Those are available in Pro and Ultimate versions.

Comment: OK. I see that: new -> project -> Smart device (I didn't know that option), and some help on on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dA517zqXijo
Thank you, that help.

Now I need to create the application at particular size (240x320 - look very very small) - How can I do that?
Also - is it matter the framework for windows ce? (2.0, 3.5)? How can I export my application to the real device?

Thanks :)